# Why doesn't the TS type system automatically narrow the type of array elements?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

As the title says, my question is - why doesn't TS automatically narrow the type of this array element:

```
// inferred type: (number | string)[]
const arr = [1, "string"];
arr[2] = "second string";

// OK
console.log(arr[2].length);

// NOK
// Property 'length' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
//  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.
console.log(arr[1].length);

// Why the type of arr[1] is not narrowed to a string??
```

This question is most likely answered already and I'm sorry if my post is considered duplication. I was trying to find an answer both from TS docs and SO but didn't manage to.

Comment: Because the semantics of inferring the type of arrays is different from the semantics of inferring assignments to array indices. I'm not sure that asking "why?" here will give you an answer that's very satisfying.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to be very specific about what you're asking?  I could write a book-length answer about "why" the compiler acts the way it acts. Briefly: { • Variables initialized by array literals are inferred as being unordered arbitrary-length arrays and not tuples, because that works well in a wide range of real-world situations (and if you want a tuple you can use a `const` assertion, or manually annotate a more appropriate type). (more)

Comment: (continued) • [Assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) only works on union-typed variables or properties.  `arr`'s type isn't a union, but `arr`'s element's types *are* unions, so assigning to `arr` doesn't narrow while assigning to `arr[2]` does. } Would an answer like that fully address your question? If so I could write one up.  If not, what am I missing?